# Названия столбцов как числа Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Как сделать названия столбцов в CSV-файле при `pandas.read_csv()` float-числами, а не строкой?
(В моем случае, название столбца = значение температуры. И все время `float'ить()` – достаточно стремно).

Comment: Вы можете задать столбцы через `dataframe.columns` и имена не обязаны быть строками. Если я правильно понял, вы получаете DataFrame, в котором названия столбцов - строки и вам нужно спарсить их к float числам?

Comment: @МаксимФисман есть файл CSV (создан самостоятельно), в котором все значения, судя по текстовым процессорам, открывающим CSV, являются числами. Но read_csv(), видимо, автоматически воспринимает их строками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто циклом спарсить названия столбцов.
Объявим DataFrame, в котором названия столбцов - строки:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0]],
    columns=['10', '55.75', '20.8'] # Строки
)
```

Преобразуем:

```
df.columns = [float(column_name) for column_name in df.columns] # Переводим в float
```

Теперь может получить столбец по числу:

```
df[55.75]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще это ещё проще делается на самом деле, чем в уже данном ответе. Довольно стандартным для `Pandas` "векторным" образом:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(float)
```

Хотя если нужно обрабатывать какие-то особые случаи, то, вероятно, тогда лучше парсить строки по отдельности.